# redirecting an onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to redirect an `onbeforeunload` with no success at all. Here's what I have so far:

window.location.href does not seem to work.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
       window.location.href = ("http://www.google.com");
        return "Are you sure you want to leave?";
};
```

This one is persistent, it redirects whether the user prompts to stay or leave. I only want to redirect when user choose to leave.

```
var stayonthis = true;
  var a;
  function load() {
   window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
        if(stayonthis){
         a = setTimeout('window.location.href="http://google.com";',100);
         stayonthis = false;    
         return "Do you really want to leave now?";
        }
        else {
            clearTimeout(a);
        }

    };
    window.onunload = function(e) {
         clearTimeout(a);
    };
  }
  window.onload = load;
```

The closest thing I could come up is this but it opens the link in new window. I only want to open the link in the same window.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        window.open("http://www.google.com");//Setting parameters to _self or _parent still opens in new window.
        return "Are you sure you want to leave?";
}
```

I'm trying to redirect to an internal url, if that matters.

Advice very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Onbeforeunload is meant to prompt users a message if you think they might need to stay on the page.  You cannot perform an action based on there response, or redirect or anything of that nature, if they click stay they stay, if they click leave they leave nothing else.

Comment: You might have posted this in the comment section. This is not an answer.

Comment: It is the answer, you cannot do what you are trying to do.